# Jmeter: Run HTTP sampler n times using the variable value from SetUp thread group variable

Tags: jmeter

We are using `Jmeter 5.1.1` v to perform load testing, Our scenario is get 25 tokens from `Setup thread group` (Threads set to 25 with rampup 25 secs under `SetUp Thread group`), then having a normal `Thread group` which contains `HTTP Sampler` and in this Sampler need to pass those 25 tokens for each 1 thread hence this Thread Group contains configuration of 25 Threads with 25 Secs.

However when Run the test, 25 tokens been generated but **only the last 25th token used for all threads** (using the 25th token). Trying to get for each Thread should get one token value, if 2nd thread then 2nd token should be used.

Below is the Structure:

```
TestPlan 
--SetUp Thread Group - 25 Threads, 25 Secs
---HTTP Sampler - Gets the Token here using RegEx and Set the value as Property using Beanshell Assertion
O/P: Got 25 tokens generated, and set in the property value

--Thread Group - 25 Threads, 25 Secs
---HTTP Sampler - Get Token value as property
O/P: Only the 25th token been used for all 25 threads
```

**EDIT**

Tried answer and got error:

[image]

[image: Error]

Comment: Why using SetUp Thread Group? why not create token inside same thread group?

Comment: Thanks for reply, SeUp Thread group token generation request we do not want to consider for results analysis, we need to analyse performance of Normal Thread group sampler request only. The token sampler is the workaround we are using to generate token by hitting API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create token inside same thread group, if you do not want to consider for results,

You can ignore token sampler by adding [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) with the line `prev.setIgnore()`

> prev - (SampleResult) - gives access to the previous SampleResult

Comment: Once again thanks for the guidance, tried by adding the suggested postprocessor and thread group contains both token and request samplers now. However getting error  (tried by selecting different languages - Java/JS/Beanshell in the JSR233 postprocessor), Attached the screen shot in the main thread. I might be doing something wrong while adding the script.

Comment: use only `prev.setIgnore()`, I'll remove the comment which isn't relevant exactly to your case

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked after adding the PostProcessor under token sampler. Thank you, working as expected now. Thanks for guiding. Accepted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing how do you pass the tokens between Thread Groups it's quite hard to tell what's wrong, a "blind shot": you're using a single JMeter Property which is being overwritten.

The solution is to make the token thread-specific, for example you can set it like:

```
props.put("token_" + (ctx.getThreadNum() + 1), vars.get("variable from regex here"));
```

and then read it using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) like:

```
${__P(token_${__threadNum},)}
```

---

Few more hints:

1. [You should be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) which is [JMeter 5.3](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-3-released-td5728863.html) as of now
2. You [should NOT be using Beanshell](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting), consider using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language
3. Passing data between threads (even if they're in different Thread Groups) is much easier with [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter/)